# Cartesian product Proof with subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Prove: $A \times A \subseteq B \times B \implies A \subseteq B$.

I just had this as a quiz question and I would like to know the correct answer. I would appreciate any help. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

Try proving the contrapositive: prove that $A \not\subseteq B \implies A \times A \not\subseteq B \times B$.

If $A \not\subseteq B$ then there is some element $x$ that is in $A$ but not in $B$. Then what can you say about the pair $(x,x)$ with respect to the cartesian product sets?